# Branch Name did not display in the left bottom corner of vs code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, branch, git-repo

Screenshot of VS Code. It helps to know about an issue which I am facing:
[image: SS of VS Code. It helps to know about an issue which I am facing]

Comment: From the image alone, it is not clear if the directory is even a git repository. Have you already initialized it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have your repository configured inside VSCode "Source Control" tab.

Click "Source Control" and see if you have any options to choose a repository (if there's no repository configured in your VSCode, you should see a notification on this tab)

[image: source control tab]

Answer (score 1):

My VSCode:

[image]

Right click in status bar and make sure source control is enable.

Answer (score 1):

On VS Code, go to View > Appearance > Check 'Status Bar' option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the status bar (where branch name should be) and make sure "Source control checkout" is checked

[image: Popup with options for displaying in status bar. Option "Source Control Checkout" is set to true and highlighted]